# Does a good manual exist for the standard C libraries?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio

Does a good manual exist for the standard C libraries? Like man for Linux or Java API.

### Edit

I am working in Visual Studio 2010 Express.

I prefer something like Java API to see all libraries and not like man that show function that I know already exists without giving me the all list of function, and also man not exist in Windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working on Unix systems the [GLibC Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/) is really good. Although it covers more than is available in standard C

Answer (score 3):

Yes... man

```
man printf
man fopen
```

And so on.

Edit:

When working on Windows with Visual Studio: use msdn site,

So instead of running

```
man printf
```

Google for

```
msdn printf
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, they are precisely specified in the ISO C standard (ISO/IEC 9899). Otherwise, most good references (*C: A Reference Manual* as well as O'Reilly's *C in a Nutshell* come to mind as C99 references) will include the information you need.

Comment: @Yosef: to be honest, the C culture predates libraries so huge they need hundreds of megabytes of HTML to describe. I usually just keep my PDF of the ISO standard open while coding and use the bookmarks to quickly look up functions---as far as knowing what functions exist, C's standard library doesn't have so many, so if you use them every day you quickly memorize the most important ones.

Answer (score 2):

Given you're using Visual Studio, the best reference is probably MSDN:

- [Visual Studio 2010 C Runtime Library Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aza74he.aspx)

This lists all the runtime functions, broken down by category.

Answer (score 1):

Install `manpages-dev` and `glibc-doc` on Debian/Ubuntu, or equivalent on other distros.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend picking up a copy of Plauger's [The Standard C Library](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131315099).